# Invalid URL 'GET': No schema supplied error while calling freebase api in Python.

Tags: python

```
import os
import shelve
import urllib
import urlparse
import sys
import shelve
import oauth2 as oauth
import requests

api_key = 'xyz'
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=hello&key=xyz'

resp, content = requests.request(url, "GET")
print resp
```

I'm just testing the freebase api. When I run this basic script, I got this error: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'GET': No schema supplied
Any reasons why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=hello&key=xyz'
>>> requests.get(url)
<Response [400]>
>>>
```

From the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) documentation

> requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
>
> It return an instance of the Response object.

So, you need to give the arguments in the right order.

```
>>> requests.request("GET",url)
<Response [400]>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the arguments in the right order: the error message makes it clear that `request()` thinks `"GET"` is the URL. Also, this call returns a single `Response` object, not separate response and content objects, so you can't unpack it to two variables.

```
resp = requests.request("GET", url)
```

Or just:

```
resp = requests.get(url)
```

Then:

```
content = resp.content
```

You should look at the documentation for the `requests` module [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/).